Magento 2: Varnish is caching for individual user
I have configured Varnish & nginx and is working fine, but I have noticed that Varnish is caching separately for each user. Suppose, I visit a page I get X-Cache: Miss and if I visit again by refreshing the page I get X-Cache: HIT and cache count now is 1.
Perfect, now that the page has been cached, I think other user's should get a faster page load and varnish should fetch data from cache. However, now if I visit the same page again from another browser, I again get X-Cache: MISS and then on refreshing I get HIT.
Is this a normal behavior? I am using Varnish configuration provided by the official Varnish docs for Magento 2.
default.vcl file:
vcl 4.1;

import std;
include "./vars.vcl";
include "./pagespeed-requirement.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "www.domain.com" || req.http.host ~ "domain.com") {
       set req.backend_hint = domain;
       return (pass);
    } else if (req.http.host ~ "www.domain2.com" || req.http.host ~ "domain2.com") {
       set req.backend_hint = domain2;
    } else {
       set req.backend_hint = default;
       return (pass);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^/.well-known/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Remove empty query string parameters
    # e.g.: www.example.com/index.html?    
    if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    # Remove port number from host header
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
    
    # Sorts query string parameters alphabetically for cache normalization purposes    
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);
    
    # Remove the proxy header to mitigate the httpoxy vulnerability
    # See https://httpoxy.org/    
    unset req.http.proxy;

    # Add X-Forwarded-Proto header when using https
    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443 || std.port(server.ip) == 8443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }
    
    # Reduce grace to 300s if the backend is healthy
    # In case of an unhealthy backend, the original grace is used
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        set req.grace = 300s;
    }
    
    # Purge logic to remove objects from the cache
    # Tailored to Magento's cache invalidation mechanism
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (purge);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
    
    # Only handle relevant HTTP request methods
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "PATCH" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          return (pipe);
    }
    
    # Only cache GET and HEAD requests
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Don't cache the health check page
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(health_check.php)$") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Collapse multiple cookie headers into one
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Remove tracking query string parameters used by analytics tools
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(_branch_match_id|_bta_[a-z]+|campid|customid|_ga|gclid|gclsrc|gdf[a-z]+|cx|dm_i|ef_id|epik|ie|igshid|cof|hsa_[a-z]+|_ke|mk[a-z]{3}|msclkid|(mtm|matomo)_[a-z]+|pcrid|p(iwi)?k_[a-z]+|redirect(_log)?_mongo_id|siteurl|s_kwcid|sb_referer_host|si|trk_[a-z]+|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(_branch_match_id|_bta_[a-z]+|campid|customid|_ga|gclid|gclsrc|cx|dm_i|ef_id|epik|ie|igshid|cof|hsa_[a-z]+|_ke|mk[a-z]{3}|msclkid|(mtm|matomo)_[a-z]+|pcrid|p(iwi)?k_[a-z]+|redirect(_log)?_mongo_id|siteurl|s_kwcid|sb_referer_host|si|trk_[a-z]+|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Don't cache the authenticated GraphQL requests
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # Add a cache variation based on the X-Magento-Vary cookie, but not for graphql requests
    if (req.url !~ "/graphql" && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    
    # Create cache variations depending on the request protocol
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        # Create cache variations based on the cache ID that is set by Magento
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
            hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);
        } else {
            # If no X-Magento-Cache-Id header is set, use the store and currency values to vary on
            hash_data(req.http.Store);
            hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
        }
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Serve stale content for three days after object expiration
  # Perform asynchronous revalidation while stale content is served
    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    # All text-based content can be parsed as ESI
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    # Allow GZIP compression on all JavaScript files and all text-based content
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }
    
    # Add debug headers
    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # Only cache HTTP 200 and HTTP 404 responses
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    }
    
    # Don't cache if the request cache ID doesn't match the response cache ID for graphql requests
    if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
       set beresp.ttl = 120s;
       set beresp.uncacheable = true;
       return (deliver);
    }

    # Remove the Set-Cookie header for cacheable content
    # Only for HTTP GET & HTTP HEAD requests
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Add debug headers
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (obj.uncacheable) {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "UNCACHEABLE";
        } else if (obj.hits) {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
    
    # Don't let browser cache non-static files
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }
    
    # Cleanup headers
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

vars.vcl file
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

backend domain {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8082";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

backend domain2 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8084";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
    }
}

# Add hostnames, IP addresses and subnets that are allowed to purge content
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "SERVER_IP";
    "::1";
}

pagespeed-requirement.vcl file
sub vcl_recv {
    call pagespeed_capability_detection;
}

# Function derived from requirements here https://modpagespeed.com/doc/downstream-caching#ps-capabilitylist
# Additional detection logic for crawlers, tablet and mobile devices.
sub pagespeed_capability_detection {
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Chrome/[3][2-9]+\.|Chrome/[4-9][0-9]+\.|Chrome/[0-9]{3,}\.") {
        # Cache-fragment 1: Desktop User-Agents that support lazyload_images (ll),
        # inline_images (ii), defer_javascript (dj), webp (jw) and lossless_webp
        # (ws).
        set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "ll,ii,dj,jw,ws:";
    } else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Firefox/[4-9].+|Firefox/[\d][\d]+|MSIE 10\.|Safari") {
        # Cache-fragment 2: Desktop User-Agents that support lazyload_images (ll),
        # inline_images (ii) and defer_javascript (dj).
        # Note: Wget is added for testing purposes only.
        set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "ll,ii,dj:";
    } else {
        # As a fallback, the PS-CapabilityList header that is sent to the upstream
        # PageSpeed server should be for a device with no browser specific optimizations.
        set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "fully general optimizations only";
    }

    # Cache-fragment 3: This fragment contains (a) Desktop User-Agents that
    # match fragments 1 or 2 but should not because they represent older
    # versions of certain browsers or bots and (b) Tablet User-Agents that
    # on all browsers and use image compression qualities applicable to large
    # screens. Note that even Tablets that are capable of supporting inline or
    # webp images, e.g. Android 4.1.2, will not get these advanced
    # optimizations.
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Firefox/[1-2]\.|MSIE [5-8]\.|bot|Yahoo!|Ruby|RPT-HTTPClient|(Google \(\+https\:\/\/developers\.google\.com\/\+\/web\/snippet\/\))|Android|iPad|TouchPad|Silk-Accelerated|Kindle Fire") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "LargeScreen.SkipUADependentOptimizations:";
    }
    # Cache-fragment 4: Mobiles and small screen Tablets will use image compression
    # qualities applicable to small screens, but all other optimizations will be
    # those that work on all browsers.
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Mozilla.*Android.*Mobile*|iPhone|BlackBerry|Opera Mobi|Opera Mini|SymbianOS|UP.Browser|J-PHONE|Profile/MIDP|portalmmm|DoCoMo|Obigo|Galaxy Nexus|GT-I9300|GT-N7100|HTC One|Nexus [4|7|S]|Xoom|XT907") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "TinyScreen.SkipUADependentOptimizations:";
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # Split cache by PageSpeed capability 
    hash_data(req.http.PS-CapabilityList);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # The following line can be uncommented for debugging purposes and will 
    # add a response header to show the header parameter sent to pagespeed.
    #set resp.http.section-io-PS-capability = req.http.PS-CapabilityList;
}

Request & Response headers given below. (Its from second request after caching).
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.domain2.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 103 
< link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.1fa7e7e0bbb47aaa3db0.js>; as=script; nopush; rel=preload, </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.1fa7e7e0bbb47aaa3db0.js.gz>; as=script; nopush; rel=preload, </runtime.120d75f4c20413a17fce.js>; as=script; nopush; rel=preload, </vendors.2510f870ac43c344ee54.js>; as=script; nopush; rel=preload, </client.157577a54c84f6c8c8a0.js>; as=script; nopush; rel=preload
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 02 Sep 2024 15:28:07 GMT
< content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< expires: -1
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-page-speed: ngx_pagespeed
< x-page-speed: ngx_pagespeed
< x-cache: HIT
< x-cache-hits: 1
< pragma: no-cache
< link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.1fa7e7e0bbb47aaa3db0.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
< link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.1fa7e7e0bbb47aaa3db0.js.gz>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
< link: </runtime.120d75f4c20413a17fce.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
< link: </vendors.2510f870ac43c344ee54.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
< link: </client.157577a54c84f6c8c8a0.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=buD7sTs4Sz%2FqHgdiYDjnZerM96%2BNXn2%2FaU3Tichce5LYkCJ3bprNtEykhKKNm82aDfpE2Bc1yEgEuzYJL86hgh4QVF3Y7VUftjqH7MRlgvji32kfbJaWOFsFOsXERwio0RY2r81ImU%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 8bce872eee157017-CDG
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
< 


Please share your full VCL file to see if it creates cache variations. Please also attach the individual HTTP request & response headers for those requests to see if Magento issues a Vary response header or if the request contains certain Cookie request headers.

@Feryn I have added the VCL and headers.

Analyzing your curl HTTP response
In terms of HTTP headers and the HTTP request, I see a cache hit in your output. Because the request is made using curl without any special arguments, there are no cookies or authorization headers sent. This means we can get a regular cache hit.
Your curl output doesn't show a Vary header either which could create cache variations in Varnish.
And that's the important first conclusion: there's nothing special happening in your output. This also means we can use the VCL code to draw conclusions.
Analyzing the VCL
The vcl_hash subroutine in VCL is used to determine how to identify an object in the cache. The standard behavior is to take the value of req.url and req.http.host and create a cache of these combined values. This effectively means the full URL is used to identify an object in the cache.
Your VCL code extends that behavior in 2 ways:

The Magento VCL extends vcl_hash.
The Pagespeed VCL extends vcl_hash.

Here's the vcl_hash definition in your Magento VCL:
sub vcl_hash {
    # Add a cache variation based on the X-Magento-Vary cookie, but not for graphql requests
    if (req.url !~ "/graphql" && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    
    # Create cache variations depending on the request protocol
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        # Create cache variations based on the cache ID that is set by Magento
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
            hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);
        } else {
            # If no X-Magento-Cache-Id header is set, use the store and currency values to vary on
            hash_data(req.http.Store);
            hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
        }
    }
}

We can skip the GraphQL part, because this is a regular request. The value of the X-Forwarded-Proto header is used as a cache variation, storing HTTP and HTTPS responses separately in the cache. This is important to avoid HTTPS redirection loops.
If your request contains the X-Magento-Vary cookie, its value will also be used to create a cache variation. But that's not the case with your request.
Here's the vcl_hash definition in your pagespeed VCL config:
sub vcl_hash {
    # Split cache by PageSpeed capability 
    hash_data(req.http.PS-CapabilityList);
}

It uses the value of the custom PS-CapabilityList request header to create cache variations. This header is created inside the custom pagespeed_capability_detection subroutine and uses the value of the User-Agent request header.
Analyzing how the PS-CapabilityList header is set, you can have an additional 5 cache variations per URL depending on the browser the user is using.
Factoring in the HTTP/HTTPS variation, you can easily have 10 variations of a cached object per URL. And that's without taking the X-Magento-Vary value into account.
Conclusion
I believe your pagespeed VCL configuration is responsible for the low hit rate and the individual caching.
You can actually see this for yourself using varnishlog. If you add the -p vsl_mask=+Hash runtime parameter to your varnishd, the varnishlog output will contain various Hash tags that describe how the caching hash is created.
By simply running varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'" you can see a full log transaction for the home page. If users get misses that should be hits, the output will describe what's going on and how the hash is created.
If pagespeed requires these cache variations, you're going to have to live with the lower hit rate. If that's not an option, you'll have to get rid of pagespeed.
